# Imagen no se muestra en el item correspondiente

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy utilizando un `RecyclerView` para mostrar una lista en los cuales cada ítem contiene texto e imágenes (La imagen la voy a buscar desde una `url` con el `ImageLoader` en el método `private void setImageNews(final ImageView view, String url)`). Al iniciar la carga de la misma, las imágenes correspondiente a cada ítem se cargan correctamente.
Pero al realizar el `scroll` hacia abajo y volviendo hacia arriba las imágenes se cargan en los **ítems que no corresponden** o no se muestran.
Mi sospecha es que al realizar el `scroll` y mandar a buscar la imagen del ítem correspondiente, cuando este ítem pierde visibilidad por el deslizamiento de la lista, el `Bitmap` obtenido del `Response` se carga en el ítem que ocupa su lugar en ese momento.
Si es así, ¿cuál es la forma correcta de manejarlo o su solución?, y si no,
¿qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?.
En el `onErrorResponse` oculto el `RelativeLayout` que contiene tanto el `ImageView` como un `ProgressBar` que se muestra mientras se va a buscar la imagen.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter .ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<DtoNews> mData;
    private Context mContext;
    private  View mView;

    public MyAdapter() {
        mData = new ArrayList();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        mView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_news, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final DtoNews news = mData.get(position);

        holder.mMessageTitle.setText(news.getmUserName());

        if(!news.getmImageUrl().equals("null")) {
            setImageNews(holder.mImageNews, news.getmImageUrl());
        } else {
            ((RelativeLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.relative_image)).setVisibility(GONE);
        }

        holder.mTextLike.setText("" + news.getmLikes());
        holder.mLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        holder.mMessageDescription.setText(news.getmDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextViewSansPro mMessageTitle;
        public final TextViewSansPro mMessageDescription;
        public final TextViewSansPro mTextLike;
        public final ImageView mImageNews;
        public final ImageView mLike;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mMessageTitle = (TextViewSansPro) view.findViewById(R.id.publisher_name);
            mMessageDescription = (TextViewSansPro) view.findViewById(R.id.text_noticia);
            mTextLike = (TextViewSansPro) view.findViewById(R.id.text_like);
            mImageNews = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_news);
            mLike = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.like_icon);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mMessageDescription.getText() + "'";
        }
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<DtoNews> data, boolean isRefresh){
        if(isRefresh) {
            mData.clear();
            mData.addAll(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else{
            mData.addAll(data);
            notifyItemRangeInserted(mData.size() - 1, mData.size() - 1 + data.size());
        }
    }

    private void setImageNews(final ImageView view, String url) {
        NetworkCacheSingleton.getImageLoader().get(url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(final ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                view.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                ((RelativeLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.relative_image)).setVisibility(GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    public ArrayList<DtoNews> getmData() {
        return mData;
    }
}
```

Un poco mas de información, esta lista funciona con paginado:
Por 1ra vez el servicio me devuelve los 1ros 5 ítems que voy a mostrar y llamo a `public void setData(ArrayList<DtoNews> data, boolean isRefresh)` para guardarlos en `ArrayList<DtoNews>`. Una vez en la lista haciendo `scroll` hacia abajo llamo al mismo servicio el cual me devuelve los siguientes 5 que voy metiendo dentro del `ArrayList` a continuación de los datos que ya estaban. Así sucesivamente hasta no obtener mas datos y tener la lista completa.
Aclaro que los datos me vienen correctamente en el orden establecido.

Answer (score 1):

Trata de usar el `setImageBitmap`:

```
holder.item_picture.setImageBitmap(item.getPhoto_bitmap());
```

Te comparto mi clase:

```
package texium.mx.drones.adapters;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import texium.mx.drones.R;
import texium.mx.drones.fragments.PhotoGalleryFragment;
import texium.mx.drones.models.DecodeGallery;
import texium.mx.drones.models.TaskGallery;
import texium.mx.drones.utils.Constants;

/**
 * Created by saurett on 14/01/2016.
 */
public class PhotoGalleryAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoGalleryAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener;
    List<TaskGallery> photo_gallery_list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView item_picture;
        Button sync_button;
        Button description_button;
        Button delete_button;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            item_picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_photo);
            sync_button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_photo_sync);
            description_button =
                (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_photo_description);
            delete_button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_photo_delete);
        }
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }
    public TaskGallery getItemByPosition(int position)
    {
        return photo_gallery_list.get(position);
    }
    public void addAll(List<TaskGallery> photos_list)
    {
        this.photo_gallery_list.addAll(photos_list);
    }
    public void remove(int position) { this.photo_gallery_list.remove(position);}

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view =
            LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_picture_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final TaskGallery item = photo_gallery_list.get(position);

        int syncType = item.getSync_type().intValue();

        int resource;
        switch (syncType) {
            case Constants.ITEM_SYNC_SERVER_DEFAULT:
                resource = R.mipmap.ic_computer_black;
                break;
            case Constants.ITEM_SYNC_LOCAL_TABLET:
                resource = R.mipmap.ic_tablet_android_black;
                break;
            case Constants.ITEM_SYNC_SERVER_CLOUD:
                resource = R.mipmap.ic_cloud_black;
                break;
            case Constants.ITEM_SYNC_SERVER_CLOUD_OFF:
                resource = R.mipmap.ic_cloud_off_black;
                break;
            default:
                resource = android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete;
                break;

        }

        final DecodeGallery decodeGallery = new DecodeGallery();

        decodeGallery.setTaskGallery(item);

        holder.sync_button.setBackgroundResource(resource);
        holder.item_picture.setImageBitmap(item.getPhoto_bitmap());

        holder.sync_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                decodeGallery.setIdView(v.getId());
                decodeGallery.setPosition(position);
                PhotoGalleryFragment.showQuestion(decodeGallery);
            }
        });

        holder.delete_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                decodeGallery.setIdView(v.getId());
                decodeGallery.setPosition(position);
                PhotoGalleryFragment.showQuestion(decodeGallery);
            }
        });

        holder.description_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                decodeGallery.setIdView(v.getId());
                decodeGallery.setPosition(position);
                PhotoGalleryFragment.showQuestion(decodeGallery);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photo_gallery_list == null ? 0 : photo_gallery_list.size();
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        this.photo_gallery_list.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount() - position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Me podrias explicar el rol que juegan `TaskGallery` y `DecodeGallery`?, ya que veo que utilizas `item.getPhoto_bitmap()` pero no entiendo como resolves el problema que planteo sobre las imagenes que no se muestran o se muestran en un item incorrecto. Estas 2 clases resuelven este problema?. Saludos.

Comment: Holas buenas noches ... **TaskGallery** y **DecodeGallery** son clases propias .. **TaskGallery** seria como un modelo el cual almacenas cada item de la lista que quieres mostrar incluidas las imagenes en el evento **onBindViewHolder** se va agregando cada item que vas iterando al decodeGallery para cuando quieras usar un listener en especifico.